# select distinct with multiple columns rails mysql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

RIght now, I have mysql database and this code:

```
Report.select('date, title, info').distinct
```

It is equivalent to this sql query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    date,
    title,
    marketplace
FROM
    reports
```

But what if I want to select not only `date, title and info`, but more params like `price`. But I want results to be distinct based only on `date,title and  info`
What do I do?
I thought of digging somewhere to group method.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to achieve this by specifying which columns the SQL query should be grouped by.

I'll show the scenario of wanting to sum the price, as an example, since you did not include how you want to use price (like Danil Speransky mentioned).

Calculate the sum of all prices per date, title and info:

```
@reports = Report.select([:date, :title, :info]).group([:date, :title, :info]).sum(:price)
(4.1ms)  SELECT SUM(`reports`.`price`) AS sum_price, date AS date, title AS title, info AS info FROM `reports` GROUP BY date, title, info
=> {["[date]", "[title]", "[info]"]=>1234,
    ["[date]", "[title2]", "[info]"]=>5678,
    ...
}
```

Which you could then loop through and access like this

```
@reports.each_pair do |columns, sum_price|
  [0] # date
  [1] # title
  [2] # info
  sum_price # The sum of all prices
end
```

Another option would be to build the select query manually like this

```
@reports = Report.select("SUM(`reports`.`price`) AS sum_price, date AS date, title AS title, info AS info").group([:date, :title, :info])
# Results in same SQL query, but will instantiate a model record for each row
=> [#<Report date: "2017-09-18", title: "[Title]", info: "[Info]">,
    #<Report date: "2017-09-18", title: "[Title2]", info: "[Info]">,
    ...
]
```

And even though the inspected records wont show the `:sum_price` column, it can still be accessed like this

```
@reports.each do |report|
  report.date
  report.title
  report.info
  report.sum_price
end
```

Comment: I think this is what I need, I will try to implement this a little bit later